# Lazy Load Twitter and Instagram Embeds on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter, instagram, lazy-loading

I’ve been trying to figure out how to lazy load all Twitter and instagram embeds on my homepage. I'm going to be adding new embeds daily and I don't want to slow the site down. http://splitsthemiddle.com.au/

There’s a few plugins that lazy load images but they do not seem to work with embeds

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks in advance